# How to insert the #byval value in the png filename when using sgplot with a by statement in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-ods, sgplot

I'm making several png image using sgplot and the `by` statement like this:

```
ods html path="&graphPath" body="index.html"
    image_dpi=300 style=sciensano1 device=png;

ods graphics on / reset noborder imagename="boom"
    height=10cm width=16cm ;

title;footnote;
options byline;
proc sgplot data=sashelp.class;
    histogram height;
    by Sex;
    run;quit;

ods html close;
```

This creates 1 html file (index.html)
and 2 png files (boom1.png & boom3.png)

I'm wondering if it's possible to name the png files according to the by values.
Similarly as adding `#byval` in the title for example.

Currently, number are added automatically to the `imagename` from the `ods graphics`, I would like to get rid of the numbers and use the byval instead.

The only solution I have so far is to make all graphs individually, using a %do loop in a macro, this way I can parametrize the imagename and give it a macro variable name. The problem with that is that it's much more complex to implement and much slower.

EDIT: Using SAS 9.3

Answer (score 1):

In my SAS 9.4M4, there is no such feature in `SGPLOT` `HISTOGRAM` options, nor in `ODS GRAPHICS`  `IMAGENAME` or `INDEX`.

Ideally, a future release would see ODS honor `#BYVAL` and `#BYVAR` substitution options.

```
ods graphics / imagename="boom#byval1";       * not real;
ods graphics / imagename="boom#byval(sex)";   * not real;
```

or

```
ods graphics / imagename="boom" reset=index(#byval1); * not real;
```

Fall back:

The `GCHART` Procedure statements, such as `VBAR` support the `name=` option which honors the `#BYVAL` substitution option.

```
vbar height / name="basename#byval1";  * creates gfx file whose name contains the by var value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this feature is in v9.4M5--dig it: [Keeping Up To Date With ODS Graphics](http://www.mwsug.org/proceedings/2018/SP/MWSUG-2018-SP-139-SAS.pdf).